# Will the coefficient value of one covariate affect the others in MLE?

Tags: statistics, partial-derivative, regression, maximum-likelihood

I am fitting a Cox Proportional Hazards model to clinical data.

Suppose I have two variables, `x` and `y`,
and the resulted coefficients are `a` for `x` and `b` for `y`.

I am curious that will the estimated value of `a` affect the estimated value of `b`?

I only know that when we try to estimate the coefficient, we set the partial derivative of the score or loss function to zero, and solve the equation.

In linear regression, when we take the partial derivative of `a`, the `b` term disappears and is not included in the results, For example,

$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\;ax+by = x$

But in exponential regression, taking the derivative of exponential will keep the both terms.
For example,

$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\;e^{ax+by} = xe^{ax+by}$

Because the partial maximum likelihood function contains many natural exponents, will the coefficients affect each other during estimation?

Comment: You are confusing the partial effects with the estimated coefficients. The estimated coeffients 
 (including OLS) will affect each other in the sense that  they might be correlated. This is because $x$ and $y$ could be correlated.

Comment: @chuck I am not quite familiar with regression. According to what you suggested, does it mean that if one coefficient is not correctly estimated (for example, the value is INF), then the values of other coefficients will also be affected, and cannot be used? My question is similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650567/r-coxph-warning-loglik-converged-before-variable-valid-results-for-other-va). Here, I want to adjust some variable, but the coefficients of that variable is exploded. So, I wonder whether the coefficients of other variables are still valid.

Comment: @chunk I understand that if variable x and y are not independent, then their estimated coefficients may affect each other, which I think is something called co-linearity? But what if the two variables are independent, will failure of one coefficient affect the other?

Comment: If they are independent, you can ignore one of them and allow it to be absorbed by the error term.

Comment: Re your second comment. Yes. If $\hat{b}$ is biased and $x$ is correlated with $y$, then $\hat{a}$ will also be biased.